# Typesetting a title on a tikzpicture (Version 3)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to put a title on a display of two similar right triangles. I provide much code here, but all that is needed is to look at the last command.  I use `current bounding box.south` to instruct `TikZ` to typeset the title at the bottom of the display.  (Is this an option for a node command?)  I specify `yshift=-3mm` in the option.  It seems to me that since the title is typeset on two lines, the middle of these two lines is typeset below the lower border of the display.  So, the top of the title interferes with the display.  How do I get the top edge of the (invisible) box containing the title to be put 3mm below the display?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}

%Rays k and $\ell$ have a common endpoint at the origin, which is labeled O. With respect to
%the horizontal line through O, k is inclined at an angle of 50 degrees, and $\ell$ is
%inclined at an angle of 15 degrees. To place the label for O, the rays are extended 15pt by an
%invisible path command "before" O. The endpoints of these extensions are called "label_O_below"
%and "label_O_above" and the midpoint of the line segment between label_O_below and label_O_above
%is called "label_O".  A node command typesets "O" at the point 7.5pt from O on the invisible
%line segment between O and label_O .
\draw[fill] coordinate (O) circle (1.5pt);

\coordinate (label_O_below) at (-130:15pt);
\coordinate (label_O_above) at (-165:15pt);
\coordinate (label_O) at ($(label_O_below)!0.5!(label_O_above)$);
\node[blue] at ($(O)!7.5pt!(label_O)$){$O$};

%Q_ray_k is a point on ray k and P_ray_ell is a point on $\ell$.
\draw[name path=ray_k, -latex,] (O) -- (50:7) coordinate (Q_ray_k);
\node (label_ray_k) at ($(Q_ray_k) + (50:7pt)$){$k$};
\draw[name path=ray_ell, -latex,] (O) -- (15:5.5) coordinate (P_ray_ell);
\node (label_ray_ell) at ($(P_ray_ell) + (15:6pt)$){$\ell$};

%This command labels a point "Q" 3.75cm from O on ray $k$.
\draw (O) -- (50:{15/4}) coordinate (Q);

%These commands label the projection of OQ onto \ell "P."  A line segment is drawn between
%Q and P, and a right-angle mark is placed at P.
\draw[name path=line_segment_QP] (Q) -- ($(O)!(Q)!(P_ray_ell)$) coordinate (P);

%These commands draw two angles - a right angle and an angle at O labeled $\theta$.
\draw pic[draw, angle radius=5mm,"$\theta$",angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = P--O--Q};

\draw ($(P)!3mm!-45:(O)$) coordinate (U) -- ($(P)!(U)!(O)$);
\draw (U) -- ($(P)!(U)!(Q)$);


%These commands draw an invisible line segment perpendicular to ray k from Q to
%ray $\ell$. The intersection is labeled P'.
\path[name path=perpendicular_line_segment_from_Q] (Q) -- ($(Q)!3.5cm!90:(O)$);
\coordinate[name intersections={of=perpendicular_line_segment_from_Q and ray_ell, by={P'}}];

%These commands draw an invisible line segment perpendicular to ray \ell from P' to ray k.
%The intersection is labeled Q'.
\path[name path=perpendicular_line_segment_from_P'] (P') -- ($(P')!4cm!90:(P_ray_ell)$);
\coordinate[name intersections={of=perpendicular_line_segment_from_P' and ray_k, by={Q'}}];
\draw (P') -- (Q');

%These commands draw a right-angle mark at P^{\prime}.
\draw ($(P')!3mm!-45:(O)$) coordinate (U') -- ($(P')!(U')!(O)$);
\draw (U') -- ($(P')!(U')!(Q')$);



%The superscript "^{\prime}" in "$Q^{\prime}$" and "$P^{\prime}$" displaces the "Q" in "$Q^{\prime}$" and the
%"P" in "$P^{\prime}$" leftward artificially by half of its width.  To cancel this artificial shift, a
%"\newlength" command is defined as the width of the subscript "^{\prime}," and the command
%"xshift=0.5\myshiftone" is issued to the node commands that position "$Q^{\prime}$" and "$P^{\prime}$."
\newlength\myshiftone
\settowidth{\myshiftone}{$^{\prime}$}


%These commands put the label "x" below line segment OP.  An invisible line segment is drawn
%2mm below OP, and "x" is typeset halfway along this invisible line segment.
\coordinate (O_shift_down_for_x) at ($(O)!2mm!-90:(P)$);
\coordinate (P_shift_down_for_x) at ($(P)!2mm!90:(O)$);
\node at ($(O_shift_down_for_x)!0.5!(P_shift_down_for_x)$){$x$};

%These commands put the label "r" above line segment OQ.  An invisible line segment is drawn
%2mm above OQ, and "r" is typeset halfway along this invisible line segment.
\coordinate (O_shift_up_for_r) at ($(O)!2mm!90:(Q)$);
\coordinate (Q_shift_up_for_r) at ($(Q)!2mm!-90:(O)$);
\node at ($(O_shift_up_for_r)!0.5!(Q_shift_up_for_r)$){$r$};


%These commands put a brace below line segment OP' and label the length `$x'$`.  This brace
%needs to be shifted downward from OP' to avoid interference with the labels O, P, and P'.
%First, coordinates for O_shift and P'_shift are defined to be 5mm from OP'.  A brace
%is drawn between O_shift and P'_shift.
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=5pt,amplitude=5pt,mirror}]
($(O)!5.5mm!-90:(P')$) coordinate (O_shift) -- ($(P')!5.5mm!90:(O)$) coordinate (P'_shift);
\coordinate (O_shift) at ($(O)!12mm!-90:(P')$);
\coordinate (P'_shift) at ($(P')!12mm!90:(O)$);
\node[xshift=0.5\myshiftone] at ($(O_shift)!0.5!(P'_shift)$){$x^{\prime}$};


%These commands put a brace above line segment OQ' and label the length `$r^{\prime}$`.  This brace
%needs to be shifted upward from OQ' to avoid interference with the labels O, Q, and Q'.
%First, coordinates for O_shift_up and P'_shift_up are defined to be 5mm from OQ'. A brace is drawn
%between O_shift_up and P'_shift_up.
\coordinate (O_shift_up) at ($(O)!5.5mm!90:(Q')$);
\coordinate (Q'_shift_up) at ($(Q')!5.5mm!-90:(O)$);
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=5pt,amplitude=5pt}] (O_shift_up) -- (Q'_shift_up);
\coordinate (O_shift_up_for_label_r') at ($(O)!12mm!90:(Q')$);
\coordinate (Q'_shift_up_for_label_r') at ($(Q')!12mm!-90:(O)$);
\node at ($(O_shift_up_for_label_r')!0.5!(Q'_shift_up_for_label_r')$){$r^{\prime}$};



%These commands draw an invisible line segment 3mm above OQ' for labels Q and Q'.
\coordinate (O_shift_for_labels_version_r') at ($(O)!3mm!90:(Q')$);
\coordinate (Q'_shift_for_labels_version_r') at ($(Q')!3mm!-90:(O)$);
\coordinate (Q'_shift_for_labels_extension) at ($(Q'_shift_for_labels_version_r')!-0.25cm!(O_shift_for_labels_version_r')$);
\path[name path=path_for_labels_Q_and_Q'] (O_shift_for_labels_version_r') -- (Q'_shift_for_labels_extension);
\path[name path=path_from_P_to_Q_above] (P) -- ($(Q)!-0.75cm!(P)$) coordinate (Q_above);
\path[name path=path_from_P'_to_Q'_above] (P') -- ($(Q')!-0.75cm!(P')$) coordinate (Q'_above);
\coordinate[name intersections={of=path_for_labels_Q_and_Q' and path_from_P_to_Q_above, by={Q_label}}];
\coordinate[name intersections={of=path_for_labels_Q_and_Q' and path_from_P'_to_Q'_above, by={Q'_label}}];
\node[green] at (Q_label){$Q$};
\node[blue, xshift=0.5\myshiftone] at (Q'_label){$Q^{\prime}$};
\node[red] at (Q'_label){$Q$};

%These commands draw an invisible line segment 2.5mm below OP' for labels P and P'. The center of the node
%containing $P'$ is displaced upwards by the subscript "1" in  $P'$. To avoid this upward vertical
%displacement, a \smash command is issued.
\coordinate (O_shift_for_labels_version_2) at ($(O)!2.5mm!-90:(P')$);
\coordinate (P'_shift_for_labels) at ($(P')!2.5mm!90:(O)$);
\path[name path=path_for_labels_P_and_P'] (O_shift_for_labels_version_2) -- (P'_shift_for_labels);
\path[name path=path_from_Q_to_P_below] (Q) -- ($(P)!-0.75cm!(Q)$) coordinate (P_below);
\path[name path=path_from_Q'_to_P'_below] (Q') -- ($(P')!-0.75cm!(Q')$) coordinate (P'_below);
\coordinate[name intersections={of=path_for_labels_P_and_P' and path_from_Q_to_P_below, by={P_label}}];
\coordinate[name intersections={of=path_for_labels_P_and_P' and path_from_Q'_to_P'_below, by={P'_label}}];
\node[green] at (P_label){$P$};
\node[blue, xshift=0.5\myshiftone] at (P'_label){$P\smash{^{\prime}}$};
\node[red] at (P'_label){$P$};


%These commands place y and y' halfway along line segments QP and Q'P'.
\path (O) -- ($(Q')!0.5!(P')$);
\coordinate (endpoint_for_line_segment_containing_labels_for_y_and_y') at ($($(Q')!0.5!(P')$)! -0.75cm! (O)$);
\path[name path=labels_for_y_and_y'_on_this_line] (O) -- (endpoint_for_line_segment_containing_labels_for_y_and_y');

\coordinate[name intersections={of=line_segment_QP and labels_for_y_and_y'_on_this_line, by={intersection_for_label_for_y}}];
\coordinate (label_for_y) at ($(intersection_for_label_for_y)! -2.5mm! (O)$);
\node[green] at (label_for_y){$y$};

\coordinate[name intersections={of=perpendicular_line_segment_from_P' and labels_for_y_and_y'_on_this_line, by={intersection_for_label_for_y'}}];
\coordinate (label_for_y') at ($(intersection_for_label_for_y')! -2.5mm! (O)$);
\node[blue, xshift=0.5\myshiftone] at (label_for_y'){$y\smash{^{\prime}}$};


\node[align=center,font=\bfseries, yshift=-3mm] at (current bounding box.south) {An illustration of similar right triangles \\ $\mathbf{\triangle{POQ}}$ and $\mathbf{\triangle{P^{\prime}OQ^{\prime}}}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `anchor=north` to the legend node.

Comment: If we only need to look at the last command, *why* do you `provide much code here`? Don't!

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina  In the syntax of the `node` command, what do you call `current bounding box.south`?  Is this a position, like `current bounding box.north`, `current bounding box.east`, and `current bounding box.west`, that `TikZ` declares for the display rendered by the preceding code?

Comment: @user74973 Yes. More-or-less. Usually. In this case, yes.

Comment: You can use [below=3mm].  It automatically will use the closest anchors (no need to specify align=north or ...south).  Note, for PRECISELY 3mm use [inner sep=0pt].